# ParDo function with more than one input

Tags: go, sdk, apache-beam

I want to use the Go SDK for Apache Beam, I'm trying to create a pipeline that computes dot product of two vectors.

```
Computesit(a, b []int)int {
return a.Dot(b)
}
A:= beam.Create(s, []int{1,2})
B:= beam.Create(s, []int{3,4})
Dot := beam.ParDo(s,Computesit, A, B)
```

But I get the following error

```
Cannot use B (type.PCollection) as type beam.Option in argument to beam.ParDo
```

My question is if it is possible, how can we emit multiple inputs to a ParDo function so?
Thank you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The question is edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the side input to supply an additional PCollection as an input. See the [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/pardo.go#L153).

There is a similar question [Go SDK Apache Beam : singleton side input Singleton for int ill-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853725/go-sdk-apache-beam-singleton-side-input-singleton-for-int-ill-defined?answertab=votes#tab-top) that has more example code in it.